# Cron job in python every x hours - 1 minute

Tags: python, cron

I would like to create a cron job that triggers at 23h59, then 3h59, 7h59, 11h59...

My solution

```
scheduler.add_job(
    func=myfunc,
    trigger="cron",
    day='*',
    hour="*/4",
    minute=59,
    second=0,
)
```

works but triggers every time one hour too late: 00.59, 4.59...
Any solution please?

Comment: Set your clock back one hour? :)

Comment: (I was joking, but it looks like some implementations of `cron` actually let you tweak the time zone `cron` uses to resolve times on a line-by-line basis. I don't know what Python package you are using or how/if it interfaces with `cron`, but that might be an option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using APScheduler. You can do

```
scheduler.add_job(
    func=myfunc,
    trigger="cron",
    day='*',
    hour="3-23/4",
    minute=59,
    second=0,
)
```

Check the scheduled times [here](https://cron.help/#59_3-23/4_*_*_*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `1/4` instead of `*/4` if you want it to run on specific hours rather than a specific period. The crontab expression syntax for this would be [`59 1/4 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#59_1/4_*_*_*). Keep in mind that this syntax is not standard, and may not work in all cron implementations